# Rounding Truncation

Tags: int, rounding

Rounding (truncation) of long decimal numbers (must again be a float!)
Use only int() and float(), * and/or /   but don't use round()

this is what I have so far

```
 x = (int(9.275))
print(x * ???)


x = (float(9.275))
print(x * ???)
```

first one needs to be rounded to 9.2
second one needs to be rounded to 9.27

How can I round these using * and or / and not use the round function?

Comment: Use the magic number `10` + some casts.

Comment: what are casts?

Comment: I added an answer below.

Comment: Please give us a clue about the language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are like casts.

You can get what you want by losing the precision:

```
float(int(9.275 * 10))/10
```

> 9.2

```
float(int(9.275 * 100))/100
```

> 9.27

---

Your attempts are not useful in order to get those expected results:

1. If you store an integer into `x` (`9`), you can't get `2` back because it is lost.

   ```
   x = (int(9.275))
   ```
2. It's not useful to get a float from `9.275` because it already has decimals:

   ```
   x = (float(9.275))
   ```

Comment: thanks it was just an exercise the above example helped me ty